# How to add space between flashcards boxes using latex flacards package?

Tags: flashcards

I'm using flacards package for making printable flashcards. At the moment, the cards are divided by grid and the columns are immediately adjacent to each other. I'm wondering how to add space between the cards, like so: [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please edit your question and add a small but complete code to demonstrate the issue, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending in `\end{document}`

Comment: Were you able to test the answer? I just updated it.

Comment: @SimonDispa, Thank you for the answer. I tried the first version from your answer and it worked! Though there was a little problem. The front and back did not align perfectly. Just tried the updated version and still not working. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Please see and try the updated answer.

Comment: @SimonDispa, I have tried the updated version. I printed the cards with two sided option as the cards have front and back sides, but they still don't aline very well (though only horizentally)...

Comment: It is not what I get. See the first figure. Perhaps is a problem with your printer? Do you turn the page and insert again in the printer manually to print the back?

Comment: Little misalignments are to be expected between  the text and the physical sheet. They are corrected in the final cut. Plus for exact align of the **text** in double side you need to use a professional printer shop.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** upon a follow up question: one side printing.

Be aware that adding space (vertical and/or horizontal) will change the size of the cards, as they are printed on a grid.

`\setlength{\cardwidthspace}{15pt}`  will add 15pt to the right of the card.

`\cardheightspace}{20pt}` will add 20pt of upper vertical space.

Normally the cards are printed with the two-sided option, which means that the odd page and the even page must be printed on a *single sheet*, using the front and back of the sheet to align their edges.

By placing two pages side by side (book view),  it can seen that the two smaller *outer margins are equal* and in the card #10 the word  "Rain" will be printed on the back of "Regen".

[image: n4b]

For cards with text on only one side, it could be more convenient to use a one side option for easier cutting.

Use `\setlength{\cardmargin}{\cardwidthspace}` to set this up.

[image: n6]

```
\documentclass[frontgrid,backgrid]{flacards}

\newlength{\cardwidthspace}
\newlength{\cardheightspace}
\newlength{\cardmargin}
\setlength{\cardmargin}{0pt}% default => two side printing <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setlength{\cardwidthspace}{15pt} % add right horizontal space
\setlength{\cardheightspace}{20pt}% add upper vertical space

\setlength{\cardmargin}{\cardwidthspace}  % use for one side printing <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<           


\usepackage{etoolbox}   % for the patch 
\patchcmd{\card}
{\front\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)}
{\front\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)\advance\cardwidth by -\cardwidthspace\relax\advance\cardheight by -\cardheightspace\relax}
{}{}

\patchcmd{\card}
{\back\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)}
{\back\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)%
        \advance\cardwidth by -\cardwidthspace\relax%
        \advance\cardheight by -\cardheightspace\relax%
        \advance\@tempdimb by \cardmargin\relax% 
    }
{}{}

\pagesetup{3}{4}

\begin{document}    
    
    \card{gehen\\schlafen}{to go/to walk\\to sleep}
    \card{hell, klar}{bright}
    \card{mit\\ohne}{with\\without}
    \card{Lernkarte}{flashcard}
    \card{Wasser}{water}
    \card{Saft}{juice}
    \card{Fenster}{window}
    \card{Linie}{line}
    \card{und\\oder}{and\\or}
    \card{Regen}{rain}
\end{document}
```